# Error in Procedure while executing the procedure

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures, plsql

I have create below procedure in my database that is populating data in one of the database table using the cursor. While executing the procedure I am getting the error:

> ORA-00911: invalid character
>       ORA-06512: at "SOURCE_PACNET.IPSERVICE_TEST_FINAL", line 43
>       ORA-06512: at line 1
>       00911. 00000 -  "invalid character"
>       *Cause:    identifiers may not start with any ASCII character other than
>                  letters and numbers.  $#_ are also allowed after the first
>                  character.  Identifiers enclosed by doublequotes may contain
>                  any character other than a doublequote.  Alternative quotes
>                  (q'#...#') cannot use spaces, tabs, or carriage returns as
>                  delimiters.  For all other contexts, consult the SQL Language
>                  Reference Manual.

Could anyone please check and let me know what is wrong in my code.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE TEST_FINAL AS
    CURSOR Cur_TieredPricing_PCT  IS
          SELECT *
            FROM IPSERVICE_46PRCT_NO4CASES_TST
        ORDER BY BILLPROFILEID, TELSTRA_SERVICE_ID;

    V_ODD_EVN            NUMBER;
    V_ID_CNT             NUMBER;
    V_IN                 VARCHAR(4) := 'In';
    V_OUT                VARCHAR(4) := 'Out';
    insertstatement      VARCHAR2(5000);
    insertstatement_1    VARCHAR2(5000);
    insertstatement_2    VARCHAR2(5000);

    Isp_TR_var           VARCHAR2(100) := 'PACNET_U_IPT_ISP_32483';

    V_CAL_TYPE           IPSERVICE_46PRCT_NO4CASES.CALCULATION__TYPE%TYPE;
BEGIN
    FOR Cur_TieredPricing_PCT_REC IN Cur_TieredPricing_PCT LOOP
        --- select count from tier_id field
        SELECT DISTINCT REGEXP_COUNT Cur_TieredPricing_PCT_REC.TIER_ID, 'EUR|JPY|KRW|GBP|TWD|SGD|HKD|USD|AUD|MYR') INTO V_ID_CNT FROM DUAL;

        DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line('V_ID_CNT is  ' || V_ID_CNT);

        SELECT Cur_TieredPricing_PCT_REC.CALCULATION__TYPE INTO V_CAL_TYPE FROM DUAL;

        DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line('CALCULATION__TYPE  ' || V_CAL_TYPE);

        IF (UPPER(V_CAL_TYPE) = 'MAXIMUM') THEN
            DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line('V_CAL_TYPE is maximum');

            FOR i IN 1 .. V_ID_CNT LOOP
                DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line('inside for loop');
                insertstatement_1      :=    'INSERT INTO  ROC_PCT_IPSERVICE_THRSHLD_TST( THRESHOLDUSAGE,RATEAMOUNT,INOUTCD,ISPID) values (Cur_TieredPricing_PCT_REC.THRESHOLD_USAGE_'
                                          || i
                                          || ',Cur_TieredPricing_PCT_REC.RATE_AMOUNT_'
                                          || i
                                          || ','
                                          || 'V_IN'
                                          || ','
                                          || 'Isp_TR_var'
                                          || ');';

                DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line('insert statement_1  ' || insertstatement_1);

                EXECUTE IMMEDIATE insertstatement_1;

                insertstatement_2      :=    'INSERT INTO  ROC_PCT_IPSERVICE_THRSHLD_TST( THRESHOLDUSAGE,RATEAMOUNT,INOUTCD,ISPID) values (Cur_TieredPricing_PCT_REC.THRESHOLD_USAGE_'
                                          || i
                                          || ',Cur_TieredPricing_PCT_REC.RATE_AMOUNT_'
                                          || i
                                          || ','
                                          || 'V_OUT'
                                          || ','
                                          || 'Isp_TR_var'
                                          || ');';

                DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line('insert statement_2  ' || insertstatement_2);

                EXECUTE IMMEDIATE insertstatement_2;

                COMMIT;
            END LOOP;
        ELSE
            DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line('V_CAL_TYPE is not maximum');

            FOR i IN 1 .. V_ID_CNT LOOP
                DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line('inside for loop');

                insertstatement      :=    'INSERT INTO  ROC_PCT_IPSERVICE_THRSHLD_TST( THRESHOLDUSAGE,RATEAMOUNT,INOUTCD,ISPID) values (Cur_TieredPricing_PCT_REC.THRESHOLD_USAGE_'
                                        || i
                                        || ',Cur_TieredPricing_PCT_REC.RATE_AMOUNT_'
                                        || i
                                        || ',Cur_TieredPricing_PCT_REC.INOUTCD, Isp_TR_var);';

                DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line('insert statement  ' || insertstatement);

                EXECUTE IMMEDIATE insertstatement;

                COMMIT;
            END LOOP;
        END IF;
    END LOOP;
END TEST_FINAL;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing a left parenthesis in call to `REGEXP_COUNT`; besides, you don't need a query for the assignment to the variable `V_CAL_TYPE`:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE TEST_FINAL AS
    CURSOR Cur_TieredPricing_PCT  IS
          SELECT *
            FROM IPSERVICE_46PRCT_NO4CASES_TST
        ORDER BY BILLPROFILEID, TELSTRA_SERVICE_ID;

    V_ODD_EVN            NUMBER;
    V_ID_CNT             NUMBER;
    V_IN                 VARCHAR(4) := 'In';
    V_OUT                VARCHAR(4) := 'Out';
    insertstatement      VARCHAR2(5000);
    insertstatement_1    VARCHAR2(5000);
    insertstatement_2    VARCHAR2(5000);

    Isp_TR_var           VARCHAR2(100) := 'PACNET_U_IPT_ISP_32483';

    V_CAL_TYPE           IPSERVICE_46PRCT_NO4CASES.CALCULATION__TYPE%TYPE;
BEGIN
    FOR Cur_TieredPricing_PCT_REC IN Cur_TieredPricing_PCT LOOP
        --- select count from tier_id field
        SELECT DISTINCT REGEXP_COUNT (Cur_TieredPricing_PCT_REC.TIER_ID, 'EUR|JPY|KRW|GBP|TWD|SGD|HKD|USD|AUD|MYR') INTO V_ID_CNT FROM DUAL;

        DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line('V_ID_CNT is  ' || V_ID_CNT);

        /* no need for a query
        SELECT Cur_TieredPricing_PCT_REC.CALCULATION__TYPE INTO V_CAL_TYPE FROM DUAL;
        */
        V_CAL_TYPE := Cur_TieredPricing_PCT_REC.CALCULATION__TYPE;

        DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line('CALCULATION__TYPE  ' || V_CAL_TYPE);

        IF (UPPER(V_CAL_TYPE) = 'MAXIMUM') THEN
            DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line('V_CAL_TYPE is maximum');

            FOR i IN 1 .. V_ID_CNT LOOP
                DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line('inside for loop');
                insertstatement_1      :=    'INSERT INTO  ROC_PCT_IPSERVICE_THRSHLD_TST( THRESHOLDUSAGE,RATEAMOUNT,INOUTCD,ISPID) values (Cur_TieredPricing_PCT_REC.THRESHOLD_USAGE_'
                                          || i
                                          || ',Cur_TieredPricing_PCT_REC.RATE_AMOUNT_'
                                          || i
                                          || ','
                                          || 'V_IN'
                                          || ','
                                          || 'Isp_TR_var'
                                          || ');';

                DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line('insert statement_1  ' || insertstatement_1);

                EXECUTE IMMEDIATE insertstatement_1;

                insertstatement_2      :=    'INSERT INTO  ROC_PCT_IPSERVICE_THRSHLD_TST( THRESHOLDUSAGE,RATEAMOUNT,INOUTCD,ISPID) values (Cur_TieredPricing_PCT_REC.THRESHOLD_USAGE_'
                                          || i
                                          || ',Cur_TieredPricing_PCT_REC.RATE_AMOUNT_'
                                          || i
                                          || ','
                                          || 'V_OUT'
                                          || ','
                                          || 'Isp_TR_var'
                                          || ');';

                DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line('insert statement_2  ' || insertstatement_2);

                EXECUTE IMMEDIATE insertstatement_2;

                COMMIT;
            END LOOP;
        ELSE
            DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line('V_CAL_TYPE is not maximum');

            FOR i IN 1 .. V_ID_CNT LOOP
                DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line('inside for loop');

                insertstatement      :=    'INSERT INTO  ROC_PCT_IPSERVICE_THRSHLD_TST( THRESHOLDUSAGE,RATEAMOUNT,INOUTCD,ISPID) values (Cur_TieredPricing_PCT_REC.THRESHOLD_USAGE_'
                                        || i
                                        || ',Cur_TieredPricing_PCT_REC.RATE_AMOUNT_'
                                        || i
                                        || ',Cur_TieredPricing_PCT_REC.INOUTCD, Isp_TR_var);';

                DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line('insert statement  ' || insertstatement);

                EXECUTE IMMEDIATE insertstatement;

                COMMIT;
            END LOOP;
        END IF;
    END LOOP;
END TEST_FINAL;
```

Comment: A left parenthesis in call to REGEXP_COUNT was present in my proc. It got deleted by mistake when I asked the question.